# Solving fopen() - permission denied on remote server without 777

Tags: php, ftp, fopen, php-5.6

I find it hard to believe that this question doesn't have an answer here, but I've searched and searched, and I can't find one.

I'm using `fopen()` on a remote server, and I only have FTP access - nothing else.

When I try to create or open a file for write access, I'm hit with the following error:

> Warning: fopen(entries/newsletter.csv): failed to open stream: Permission denied in 
>   /var/www/sites/xxx/public_html/index.php on line 24
>   Error: Can't open file. Your entry was not saved.

I've tried changing the file permissions to 777 and opening the existing file, and **it works!** But that cannot be a recommended solution, as 777 is so insecure.

Is there any way I can resolve this over FTP without resorting to 777?

Answer (score 2):

Can you not change the parameters on the open to try to simply open in Read Only mode? [PHP Manual for fopen() options.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

```
fopen("csv/newsletter.csv", "r");
```

This uses the least permissions, but you do need to have read access.   Of course, you cannot write to the file.  Also, 777 includes executable bit, so you might just want 666.

You could also try connecting via the FTP as a user, and ensure that users permission to the file is rw (6) and then others, do not need that setting so they could be read only.

Optionally through your FTP interface, maybe chmod() the file to be read/write before opening, then chmod read only after.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to write to the file. I have only one login for the FTP.

Comment: You can set the file permissions for the one login to be rw (6) and then the others at a different value. The other option might be to chmod (666) the file when you go to access it via the FTP interface, and then set it back after with another chmod.

Comment: I am unable to set permissions for the login, unfortunately. I'm very limited!